# Adjusting Plot Margins or Create Semi-Circle

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to create the image below. However, I need to change the circle in the middle of the field to only be a semi-circle or find a way such that `ggplot` saves the image without any margins.

I have tried adjusting the margins and looked into how to make a semi-circle, but I have only found plots with all circles that are then transformed into polar coordinates.

Code:

```
p <- ggplot() +
  #Pitch
  geom_rect(aes(xmin = 100, xmax = 101, ymin = 44.7, ymax = 55.1), fill = NA, colour = "black", size = 1) + # Goal
  geom_rect(aes(xmin = 50, xmax = 100, ymin = 0, ymax = 100), fill = NA, colour = "black", size = 1) + # Field Around
  geom_rect(aes(xmin = 83, xmax = 100, ymin = 21, ymax = 79), fill = NA, colour = "black", size = 1) + #18yrd box
  geom_rect(aes(xmin = 100, xmax = 94, ymin = 36.8, ymax = 63.2), fill = NA, colour = "black", size = 1) + #6yrd box
  geom_point(aes(x = 88.5, y = 50), colour = "black", size = 1.5) + #PK spot
  geom_point(aes(x = 50, y = 50), colour = "black", size = 2) + #Centre circle dot
  geom_point(aes(x = 50, y = 50), colour = "black", size = 55, shape = 1) + #centre circle 
  geom_rect(aes(xmin=49, xmax=50,ymin=0,ymax=100),fill='white',color='white',size=1)+
  coord_flip() +
  xlim(50, 101) +
  ylim(0,100)+
  #Theme
  theme(
    panel.background = element_rect(fill = "transparent",colour = NA),
    plot.margin = unit(c(0,0,0,0), "cm"),
    plot.title = element_text(size = 14, hjust = 0.5, vjust = 1.25),
    plot.background = element_rect(fill = "transparent", colour = NA),
    line = element_blank(),
    axis.title.x = element_blank(),
    axis.title.y = element_blank(),
    axis.text = element_blank(),
    legend.position = "none",
    legend.box = "vertical",
    legend.background = element_rect(fill = "transparent")
  )
  p
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a semi-circle using `geom_arc()` from the ggforce package.

```
library(ggforce)

ggplot() +
  #Pitch
  geom_rect(aes(xmin = 100, xmax = 101, ymin = 44.7, ymax = 55.1), fill = NA, colour = "black", size = 1) + # Goal
  geom_rect(aes(xmin = 50, xmax = 100, ymin = 0, ymax = 100), fill = NA, colour = "black", size = 1) + # Field Around
  geom_rect(aes(xmin = 83, xmax = 100, ymin = 21, ymax = 79), fill = NA, colour = "black", size = 1) + #18yrd box
  geom_rect(aes(xmin = 100, xmax = 94, ymin = 36.8, ymax = 63.2), fill = NA, colour = "black", size = 1) + #6yrd box
  geom_point(aes(x = 88.5, y = 50), colour = "black", size = 1.5) + #PK spot
  geom_point(aes(x = 50, y = 50), colour = "black", size = 2) + #Centre circle dot

  geom_arc(aes(x0 = 50, y0 = 50, r = 22.5, start = 0, end = 180), size = 1) +

  coord_flip() +
  xlim(50, 101) +
  ylim(0,100)+
  #Theme
  theme(
    panel.background = element_rect(fill = "transparent",colour = NA),
    plot.margin = unit(c(0,0,0,0), "cm"),
    plot.title = element_text(size = 14, hjust = 0.5, vjust = 1.25),
    plot.background = element_rect(fill = "transparent", colour = NA),
    line = element_blank(),
    axis.title.x = element_blank(),
    axis.title.y = element_blank(),
    axis.text = element_blank(),
    legend.position = "none",
    legend.box = "vertical",
    legend.background = element_rect(fill = "transparent")
  )
```

[image: plot]

Note: I know nothing about sports, & have no idea what this field's appropriate dimensions should be. You may need to adjust the values to get the circle to look circular...

Comment: adjusting coordinates is the easy part! Figure out how to draw is the difficult part!

Answer (score 0):

[`ggsoccer`](https://github.com/Torvaney/ggsoccer) can also draw soccer fields (the package is not on CRAN but it's on Github)